# reading a file and storing values in a matrix using python

Tags: python, file, list, matrix

I am trying to read some numbers from a file and store them into a matrix using Python. In the file, on the first line, I have 2 numbers, n and m, the number of lines and the number of columns and on the next lines, I have n*m values. The complicated part is that in the file, on the second line, for example, I do not have m values, I have only m-2 values. So I cannot read the file one line at a time and just store the values in a matrix. Editing the file is not option because I have files which have 200 rows and 1000 columns.
This is how a file with less rows and columns looks:

```
4 5
1 2 3 
4 5 1 2 3 4 
5 1 2 
3 4 5 1 2 
3 4 5
```

I have managed to resolve this problem by storing all the values in an array and then deleting the first two values, which are n and m, and then creating a matrix from that array.

This is my code:

```
f = open('somefile2.txt')
numbers = []
for eachLine in f:
    line = eachLine.strip()
    for x in eachLine.split(' '):
        line2 = int(x)
        numbers.append(line2)
f.close()
print numbers
n = numbers[0]
del numbers[0]
m = numbers[0]
del numbers[0]
print n, m, numbers
vector = []
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        vector.append(numbers[j])
    matrix.append(vector)
    vector = []
print matrix
```

This gives me the expected result, but is this the right way to do it, by using the extra array `numbers`, or is there an easier way in which I store all the values directly into a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator function:

```
def solve(f, n, m):
    lis = []
    for line in f:
        if len(lis) > m:
            yield lis[:m]
            lis = lis[m:]
        lis.extend(map(int, line.split()))
    for i in xrange(0, len(lis), m):
        yield lis[i:i+m]       

with open('abc1') as f:
    n, m = map(int, next(f).split())
    # Now you can either load the whole array at once using the list() call,
    # or use a simple iteration to get one row at a time.
    matrix = list(solve(f, n, m))
    print matrix
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

---

Another approach get a flattened iterator of all the items in the file, and then split that iterator into equally sized chunks.

```
from itertools import chain, islice

with open('abc1') as f:
    n, m = map(int, next(f).split())
    data = chain.from_iterable(map(int, line.split()) for line in f)
    matrix = [list(islice(data, m)) for i in xrange(n)]
    print matrix
    #[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

---

**Related:**

- [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)
- [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: Thank you! It works with the first version. I will also try the second approach. I have another question: at the notifications I saw that I received 2 answers for my question, but I can only see your answer. Do you know why?

Comment: @user1956190 Other answer is deleted now, only users with 10K+ rep can see deleted posts.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    strings = f.read().split()

numbers = map(int, strings)
m = numbers.pop(0)
n = numbers.pop(0)

matrix = [numbers[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, m*n, n)]
```

In Python 3 you would simply do:

```
m, n, *numbers = map(int, strings)
```

Depending on what you want to do with the data you might want to have a look at NumPy which has some nice methods for reading text files.